# Product variation has a setting for "any" variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the code below to create a variable product programmatically but the created product has a variation of "Any Badge ID". For example, I want a product variation with the badge ID 1000 with a set price and quantity.

```
/* Set the product attribute */
$attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
$attribute->set_name( 'Badge ID' );
$attribute->set_options( array( '1000' ) );
$attribute->set_position( 0 );
$attribute->set_visible( true );
$attribute->set_variation( true );
$product->set_attributes( array( $attribute ) );    

$product->save();
$product_id = $product->get_id();

// Create the variation for the player product
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
$variation->set_virtual( true );
$variation->set_regular_price( $starting_price ); // in current currency
$variation->set_parent_id( $product_id );
$variation->set_attributes( array('Badge ID' => '1000') );
$variation->set_manage_stock(true);
$variation->set_stock_quantity( STARTING_STOCK);
$variation->set_stock_status('instock');                
$variation->save();
```

How can I set the product variation to be `1000` instead of a variation for `Any Badge ID`?

Comment: @DarkBee Sorry. I've updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the product variation to a specific badge ID (e.g., 1000) instead of "Any Badge ID," you need to ensure that you are correctly setting the attribute options and variation data. Here's an updated version of your code to achieve this:

```
// Set the product attribute
$attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
$attribute->set_name('Badge ID');
$attribute->set_options(array('1000')); // Set the desired badge ID as an option
$attribute->set_position(0);
$attribute->set_visible(true);
$attribute->set_variation(true);
$product->set_attributes(array($attribute));

$product->save();
$product_id = $product->get_id();

// Create the variation for the product
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
$variation->set_regular_price($starting_price); // in current currency
$variation->set_parent_id($product_id);

// Set variation attributes
$variation->set_attributes(array('badge_id' => '1000')); // Use the attribute name and option value
$variation->set_manage_stock(true);
$variation->set_stock_quantity(STARTING_STOCK);
$variation->set_stock_status('instock');

// Set the variation title (optional but recommended)
$variation->set_title('Badge ID 1000');

$variation->save();
```

**In this code:**
I've adjusted the set_attributes method for the variation to use the attribute name (badge_id) and the desired option value ('1000').
I've added a line to set the variation title using set_title. This step is optional but can be helpful for identification.
Ensure that you are using the correct attribute name ('Badge ID') and the exact option value ('1000') that matches the options you set for the attribute. This should result in a variation specifically for "Badge ID 1000" instead of "Any Badge ID."

**Here's an alternative solution:**

```
// Set the product attribute
$attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
$attribute->set_name('Badge ID');
$attribute->set_options(array('1000')); // Set the desired badge ID as an option
$attribute->set_position(0);
$attribute->set_visible(true);
$attribute->set_variation(true);
$product->set_attributes(array($attribute));

$product->save();
$product_id = $product->get_id();

// Create the variation for the product
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
$variation->set_regular_price($starting_price); // in current currency
$variation->set_parent_id($product_id);

// Set variation attributes
$variation->set_attributes(array('badge_id' => '1000')); // Use the attribute name and option value
$variation->set_manage_stock(true);
$variation->set_stock_quantity(STARTING_STOCK);
$variation->set_stock_status('instock');

// Set the variation title (optional but recommended)
$variation->set_title('Badge ID 1000');

// Set this variation as the default
$product->set_default_attributes(array('badge_id' => '1000'));
$product->set_variation_default($variation->get_id());

$variation->save();
$product->save();
```

In this version, the set_default_attributes() method is used to set the default variation attributes, and set_variation_default() is used to mark the variation as the default. This should achieve the same result of having the variation with badge ID 1000 as the default instead of "Any Badge ID."

Comment: Somehow, I managed to solve it by using `$variation->set_attributes( array('attribute_token-id' => $starting_token_id) );` but not sure if this is the best approach since there're so many ways to code for WooCommerce.

Comment: Certainly! When setting the product variation in WooCommerce programmatically, use $variation->set_attributes( array('attribute_slug' => 'option_value') );. This provides a concise and specific way to handle variations.

Feel free to reach out if you have any more questions or if there's anything else I can help you with!